# how to set DeleteOnTermination in aws php sdk?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I'm working off this documentation: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonEC2/modify_instance_attribute

This is the best I can make sense of the docs:

```
$instance_id = 'i-XXXXXXXX';
$volume_id = 'vol-XXXXXXXX';

$ec2->modify_instance_attribute ( $instance_id, array(
    'Attribute' => 'blockDeviceMapping',
    'BlockDeviceMapping' => array(
            array(
                    'DeviceName' => '/dev/sdh',
                    'Ebs' => array(
                            array(
                                    'VolumeId' => $volume_id,
                                    'DeleteOnTermination' => true
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
));
```

But the call returns with

```
[Error] => CFSimpleXML Object
(
    [Code] => InvalidParameterCombination
    [Message] => No attributes specified.
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct as such: I copied it verbatim, changed nothing but `$instance_id` and `$volume_id` (as well as `DeviceName` to an existing one on an [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) test instance) and it returns properly with HTTP status 200.

Are you sure you are running the latest [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) (not that I'd be aware of a specific issue, but that's the one which is working for me right now)?